# Self blocking session

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

we are experiencing unresponsive Sql Server 2008 R2 Web Edition. The only way how to connect to the server is via DAC.

The `dm_os_tasks` return 539 tasks almost all SUSPENDED or PENDING. There is one task with `blocking_session_id` same as `session_id`. It's waiting for `LCK_M_SCH_M`, the others tasks are waiting for `TEMPOBJ`.

Both `LCK_M_SCH_M` and `TEMPOBJ` are weird. There is no scripts for changing/creating/droping schema. We are not using any temporary tables, only table variables and table-UDT as input parameters for several functions and stored procedures.

The task with `LCK_M_SCH_M` is inline-table-function with table-UDT (`TblGuid`).
The UDT `TblGuid` is table with single column:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TblGuid] AS TABLE(
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
)
```

The table-valued-function is unchanged for months and is called a lot. This behaviour became "out of nowhere".

If we restart the sql server service, all became ok. This state occures +- 10x in day.

I suspect the same `session_id` and `blocking_session_id` is invalid state and could not appears. Am I right?

**EDIT:**
The problematic function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUnits_By_IDsBattleTargets_As_CurrentUnitModel] 
(   
    @IDsBattleTargets [dbo].[TblGuid] READONLY,
    @IDCurrentPlayer uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        U.IDUnitClass,
        U.IDBattleTarget,
        U.Amount
    FROM @IDsBattleTargets AS IDS
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblBattleTarget] AS BT
        ON BT.BattleTargetID = IDS.Guid
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblUnit] AS U
        ON U.IDBattleTarget = IDS.Guid
    LEFT JOIN [cache].[tblHeroSharingWithPlayerClan] AS HSWPC
        ON HSWPC.IDHero = IDS.Guid
            AND HSWPC.IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer
    LEFT JOIN [cache].[tblHeroSharingWithAlliance] AS HSWPA
        ON HSWPA.IDHero = IDS.Guid
            AND HSWPA.IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer
    WHERE U.Amount > 0
        AND (BT.IDBattleTargetOwner = @IDCurrentPlayer
            OR HSWPA.IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer
            OR HSWPC.IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer)
)
```

The function is called from another function or from C# (.NET 4.0) via SqlConnection,SqlCommand and SqlParameter.

**SOLUTION:**
After advices I decided for change TVP to something another. I choosed the `varbinary(max)` where one Guid/uniqueidentifier value has 16 bytes. I created sql-clr function with `varbinary(max)` input and table output `Guid uniqueidentifier`. I won't use spliting text because it's not much efficient for my purpose (this function is called very often). After the 30 hours in production (the problem occured only on one server in production, and we was not able reproduce them in testing environment) there was no problem. Usualy the problem occures several times a day. This will be propably solution.

In the final the function looks:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUnits_By_IDsBattleTargets_As_CurrentUnitModel] 
(   
    @IDsBattleTargets varbinay(max),
    @IDCurrentPlayer uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        U.IDUnitClass,
        U.IDBattleTarget,
        U.Amount
    FROM [dbo].[GetGuidsFromBinary](@IDsBattleTargets) AS IDS
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblBattleTarget] AS BT
        ON BT.BattleTargetID = IDS.Guid
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblUnit] AS U
        ON U.IDBattleTarget = IDS.Guid
    LEFT JOIN [cache].[tblHeroSharingWithPlayerClan] AS HSWPC
        ON HSWPC.IDHero = IDS.Guid
            AND HSWPC.IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer
    LEFT JOIN [cache].[tblHeroSharingWithAlliance] AS HSWPA
        ON HSWPA.IDHero = IDS.Guid
            AND HSWPA.IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer
    WHERE U.Amount > 0
        AND (BT.IDBattleTargetOwner = @IDCurrentPlayer
            OR HSWPA.IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer
            OR HSWPC.IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer)
)
```

If someone will have similar issue, please contact me. I would like to more investigate this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not blocking itself, this is just an odd artifact of how the waits are being reported. (And no, this isn't an invalid state, it happens all the time and is not indicative of any bug or deeper problem.) This has been reported a few times with table variables, and I think TVPs is a relatively newer one where there might still be some unresolved issues.

Some minor thoughts on optimization. First of all, why is the Guid column in the table type nullable? Why isn't it a primary key? The optimizer will be able to do a lot more with this if it understands the cardinality better, and your C# code is certainly capable of ensuring that it doesn't populate the parameter with duplicates or null values.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TblGuid] AS TABLE(
    [Guid] [uniqueidentifier] PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Now, the function has a lot of joins that I think are unnecessary, and if you can perform the grouping outside the function that may be better. I don't have sample data to verify that this returns the same results as your existing function, but if it's off it shouldn't be off by much. When you get it returning the same results, please do compare the actual execution plans and I am confident you will find this version is better.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUnits_By_IDsBattleTargets_As_CurrentUnitModel] 
(   
    @IDsBattleTargets [dbo].[TblGuid] READONLY,
    @IDCurrentPlayer  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- added this 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT
        U.IDUnitClass,
        U.IDBattleTarget,
        U.Amount
    FROM dbo.tblUnit AS U
    WHERE U.Amount > 0 
    AND EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tblBattleTarget AS BT 
        WHERE BT.BattleTargetID IN (SELECT Guid FROM @IDsBattleTargets
          WHERE Guid = U.IDBattleTarget))
    )
    AND EXISTS 
    ( 
      SELECT 1 FROM cache.[tblHeroSharingWithPlayerClan]
        WHERE IDHero IN (SELECT Guid FROM @IDsBattleTargets)
        AND IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 1 FROM cache.[tblHeroSharingWithAlliance]
        WHERE IDHero IN (SELECT Guid FROM @IDsBattleTargets)
        AND IDPlayer = @IDCurrentPlayer
    )
    -- only if necessary:
    -- GROUP BY U.IDUnitCass, U.IDBattleTarget, U.Amount
);
```

Comment: The function is inline-table-valued function. I need pass the array of Guid to the function and I need it as function (for further JOINs). The only workaround for using TblGuid type I know the parsing CSV passed as nvarchar. However it's not much good in performance. Is there another way?

Comment: How are you splitting the GUIDs now? [Try my answer here which does exactly that - splits a comma-separated list of GUIDs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044138/stored-procedure-passing-guids-as-csv-string/), using an inline table-valued function. If you want help improving your function, please post the function code. You should also let us know how many GUIDs we're talking about.

Comment: I know difference between multistatement and inline function :). I added the "edit" section to the question.

Comment: That wasn't clear initially, sorry. Anyway I am just suggesting a possible workaround. While the TVP might be a logical choice because it *should* be faster, if it is causing this issue you might not get to the bottom of why, or it may take a long time. In the meantime an "old-school" method might not be as fast, but if it doesn't hang up your server and require you to use DAC to overcome, I'd prefer that. A rocket will get me to Buffalo faster than my car, but if I can't steer the rocket, I think I'd rather arrive alive than late.

Comment: Or arrive alive *and* late, even. (Must be Monday.)

Comment: Unfortunately the performance is required in this case. When our server is under load, this function is called often. Parsing text will be propably causing another problem. However we have several functions and procedures with TVP and they does not appeared as problematic. Unless the one function which is 90% same with only little changes. But this function is always in LCK_M_SCH_M lock in dm_os_tasks when incident became.

Comment: Well I don't know what else to tell you. You want to use the "faster" function even though it locks up your server and requires DAC. Ok, have fun. Have you considered optimizing by doing things like removing `DISTINCT` from the function definition, and grouping by on the outer results instead of forcing the function to do that work? Have you looked at the execution plan of the function to see where there might be other potential issues?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I'll try grouping and I'll will not investigate more the same values in session_id & blocking_session_ids. If it will help, I'll be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: You shouldn't accept my answer unless it actually helps solve your problem (my answer above mostly just addresses the question about self-blocking, which is just a symptom of the actual problem). I still think that trying the "old school" method, while in theory a bit slower, is worth some investigation.

Comment: If it will helps my server run and customers will not waiting ages for results, the problem will be solved and your answer will be definetly worth for accept :).

Comment: Thanks for moving the question. This is propable much better site to ask. I changed the the TVP to the varbinary(max) and created clr function which accept varbinary(max) and returns the guids in table form. Its faster than spliting text. Now its in production I must wait some time for collecting results. I have not good experience with subselects because of performance. Joins made us much better performance. However, if change from TVP to varbinary(max) will not help, I'll try you solution. Thank's a lot for your concern. Your advices are best I found on the net.